# Rails Active Record Query Finding Item Out Of Scope

Tags: rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2, active-record-query

I'm not sure I fully understand active record querying, but I am running into a very peculiar issue where my active record conditionals seem to be pulling in items outside my current scope. Here is an example of what I am seeing:

In Rails 2.3 console

```
>> Transaction.single_card.find(:all).map(&:id)
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>> Transaction.single_card.find(:all, :conditions => "cards.number = '1234'").map(&:id)
=> [9]

<this line added because the [9] was being cut in half by scroll bar>
```

How is this happening? Why, when I add extra conditions to my query, do I pull a record that should not be there at all? From my understanding, the extra conditional should check Transactions 0..5 (the transactions with a single card) and see if the card number is 1234. But the query pulls Transaction 9, which has 2 cards associated with it, which is why it did not appear in the initial query. What is going on?

Extra note: The single_card named scope :includes the cards reference

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to accomplish with your query?

Comment: Find the correct transaction. Basically I have a page with a card number input field. This card number is used to find a valid transaction (valid transactions for this particular flow are transactions with a single card associated to it). I ran into a bug in testing where I input the card number of a transaction with multiple cards expecting nothing to return. To my surprise a transaction came back. I checked the database and sure enough, my transaction had 2 cards associated with it, even though I only wanted to search for single_card transactions. Thats when I ran the example above.

Comment: So is the problem you're trying to solve is that you only want to return one record even if multiple are available?

Comment: Here is a more verbose example. Hopefully it lays out what the problem is.
https://gist.github.com/lalibelamonk/672e24a5f058a9cc4a796750ce669e2c

Comment: Ahhh, I'm tracking with you now. And your `single_card` scope looks like this - `scope :single_card, -> { includes(:cards) }` - correct?

Comment: Updated my gist above to include the named scope

Comment: Is the number attribute in 'Card' table a string or a integer datatype? What is the the card's number for transaction number 9? Is it also '1234'?